# Migrate getInitialProps from page router to app router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, app-router

In the page router we use getInitialProps to get important data then pass in all over the app. Like below.

```
App.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
    let pageProps = {};
    const response = await axios.get(url, payload);
    const { user, store } = response.data;
    pageProps.user = user;
    pageProps.store = store;
    return {
      pageProps,
    };
})

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
return <Component {...pageProps} />
})
```

Now how we are going to do this in App Router. Are we going to use redux or some kind of global state management or what. For example like this in Layout of app router

```
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
const user = await getUserData();
return (
<html lang="en">
  <Provider value={user}>
  <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
  </Provider>
</html>
);
}
```

I am new to app router so any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can move the code into the body of the layout/page/component now.